# Can an Apache-served pure-HTML website be hacked?

Tags: security

Assume you are running a pure-HTML website on Apache. Just serving static files, nothing dynamic, nothing fancy.

Also assume all passwords are safe, and no social-hacking (i.e. phishing attacks, etc...)

Can a website of this nature basically be hacked? Can the server become compromised? Are there any examples for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be curious to read an **[article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/2415-7343_11-159903.html)** or **[two](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm)** about **"[Securing Apache 2](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1786)"**.

It is reasonable to say it is secure, but you may want to take note that Apache *does come shipped with some modules already enabled*.

Also, the goal of securing Apache should not only to secure the server instance itself, but to **sandbox the server in such a way that you would limit the damage any such intrusion could do**.

All of this information is of course contingent on the web server being the only exposed component on the box.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, such a server can become compromised. A very common vector, sadly, is FTPing to the server over an insecure wifi connection. Anyone listening closely can pick your password out of the air. (It's fun to be at a tech conference and have your password displayed on a screen for all to see, along with the other fools that sent their credentials in the clear over wifi.)

Another common vector is using a simple password and having it fall to a dictionary attack.

Answer (score 5):

Sure it can be compromised, through security flaws in Apache itself.  While it's true that adding more layers (like php, sql, etc) onto the server itself increases the potential for vulnerability, nothing is infallible.

Apache, however, is a very well-known open-source program, and the community does a good job of flushing out bugs like this.

Short answer:  any internet-connected device has the potential to be "hacked"

Answer (score 0):

Anything "hackable" about the website itself would have to be a hack in Apache itself. If so, you've got bigger problems than just one website.

So, on a practical level, nope, given the "all password files are safe" conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it could be hacked but in theory anything can be hacked. In practice no. Because Apache didn't had any important vulnerabilities for several years.